# Как избежать sql запроса в запросе. node.js mysql expressjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, jade

Необходимо сделать динамическое меню и по нажатию ссылки на блок выводить контент, сделал так:

```
app.get('/block/:id', function(req, res){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM block WHERE date="2016-01-11"', function(err, rows1){
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM block JOIN content ON content.block_id=block.block_id WHERE block.block_id='+ req.params.id, function(err, rows2){
      res.render('index', {block : rows1, title: 'title', content : rows2});
    });
  });
});
```

Есть другие варианты?

```
html
  head
    title=title
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/style.css")
  body
    .container
      each blockLink in block
        p
          a(href="/block/#{blockLink.block_id}") #{blockLink.name}
    .container2
      each contentLink in content
        p
          a(href="/#{contentLink.title_id}") #{contentLink.text}
```

Comment: Для чего именно используется первый запрос?

Comment: [union](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/UNION.html)

Comment: @Darth, с union могут быть проблемы, если каждый запрос возвращает больше одной строки

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Первый запрос берет из базы разделы со временем (11:30, 12:30 и т.д.) по дате, второй какие задачи есть на это время, их большое количество.

Comment: @Ezi А почему второй запрос от первого никак не зависит ? возвращаемые им данные что ли одинаковы для всех строк из первого запроса ? Ну тогда выполните второй запрос первым, соберите результаты в массив и в цикле запроса который сейчас первый просто берите строки из этого массива. Хотя никто не мешает сделать 1 запрос. Надо только понять точно что же он должен дать

Comment: @Ezi, как вариант, результат выполнения первого запроса можно закешировать.

Comment: @Mike Просто список разделов нужен на каждой странице.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Как вариант - http://javascript.ru/forum/node-js-io-js/51213-node-js-sokhranit-rezultat-callback-funkcii.html ?